# jQuery/CSS related problem

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new to jQuery, and this is the page I'm currently developing.

http://90.230.237.71/gandhi.html (Hope that works now :P)

I'm testing your tips on page gandhi2.html

When I hit "Show/hide gallery" all the images are first opened vertically, and later they are corrected to their horizontal placement, that's the problem. They should be horizontal right away! I don't know if this is due to jQuerys slideDown or entirely CSS-related, but the code is all there for you.

Initally, the images are set to display: none, perhaps they then are invisibly stored vertically. Then slideDown is performed and last, the CSS-attributes are changed to "display: inline". Perhaps I need to change execution order of slideDown and setting the CSS-attributes... but how?

I NEED HELP... for many reasons, but I only want you to help me with this one ;)

And also, please actually look at the code before making any assumptions. It's *all* there in the code.

## EDIT

Has got it working by changing one line in jQuery. Line 5738 I changed from
this.elem.style.display = "block";
to
this.elem.style.display = "inline-block";

Do I need to use my own modified version of jQuery or can I simply override that value from my html-page? Perhaps I should start a new thread for that question...

Answer (score 0):

They are showing horizontally to me when I hit the "Show/hide gallery" link. Also, try hiding with jquery in `ready` handler rather than using `display:none` in CSS so that jquery remembers their initial display settings eg `block`, etc.

```
$(function()){
  $('.gallery_container img').hide();
};
```

Comment: Will do that. What browser are you using?

Comment: @MrAwesome: Firefox 3.6.2, and possibly it could be a browser specific problem, check your markup as well.

Answer (score 0):

`slideDown` sets the `display` CSS property to `block`; which you seem to have realised, as you change it to `inline` in your `slideDown` callback.

Instead of animating each image individually, you should wrap them in a block level element (the `ul.navlist`?), and `slideDown()` that instead.

Comment: I want to show the first 5 pictures, and slide down the rest of the gallery. Therefore I can't slideDown the entire ul... right?

Answer (score 0):

In your stylesheet, try setting the `li` elements to `display: inline-block`. Then at the start of your jQuery, use `$(/*li elements*/).hide()`.

### EDIT:

Found the problem: http://dev.jquery.com/browser/trunk/jquery/src/fx.js#L269

### EDIT 2:

Fixed: http://www.jsfiddle.net/aUAAm/

Comment: Didn't work. The solution has to be what Matt is talking about. slideDown changes display to block. If I just can keep it inline during its execution, the problem might be solved. I dont't have a clue how though :P